# Magento 2 : add tier price programatically for all customer Group

Tags: magento2, programmatically, tierprice

How to add Tier Price programatically for all customer group

Tried below not working.

As ALL GROUP id is 32000;

```
$sku = "test";
$customerGroupId = 32000;
$price = 5.5;
$qty = 2;

$tierPrice = $obj->create('Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductTierPriceManagementInterface')->add($sku, $customerGroupId, $price, $qty);
echo "done";
```

Comment: You forgot to add $tierPrice->save();

Comment: @RohanHapani above code is working for other ids only 32000 has the no such entity error

Comment: it might not be present in customer group. please make sure that id is available or not

Answer (score 0):

Check the below code for set tier prices.

```
class Product extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{
    protected $_productloader;  

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory $_productloader

    ) {


        $this->_productloader = $_productloader;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }
    public function getLoadProduct($id)
    {
        return $this->_productloader->create()->load($id);
    }

    public function setTierPriceForGroup(){
        $tierPrices[] = array(
             'website_id'  => 0,
             'cust_group'  => 32000,
             'price_qty'   => 2,
             'price'       => 5.5
        );

        $product_id = 1; //PASS YOUR PRODUCT ID HERE   
        $product = $this->getLoadProduct($product_id);
        $product->setTierPrice($tierPrices);
        $product->save();
    }
}
```